# Deploy Django Prject in AAPnael

Tags: python, django

Does someone how to deploy a Django Project in AAPanel?

I tried Python Maganer 2.0 but impossible for me!

### I get this error:

### Sorry, something went wrong：
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "class/flask_sockets.py", line 30, in **call**
handler, values = adapter.match()
File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1945, in match
raise NotFound()
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

...and many others after that....

Please help me